# Curious about "but with" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Please explain how we replace the first sentence with the second one.  I do not understand the rule. Could we use "with + noun"  for any situation in this kind of context?

> 1. Thursday will be colder, but we will have less rain.
> 2. Thursday will be colder, but with less rain.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the first sentence. Its fairly standard English (at least I assume since I understood it with not a second thought). The only thing that might have thrown the poster above off is the formality of it. i.e. while grammatically correct, 9/10 you won't hear:

> Thursday will be colder, but we will have less rain.

Instead you'll hear:

> Thursday will be colder (than x-day), but we'll probably have less rain (than x-day).

The flow was off. It was missing something to be *compared to*. You can put the day being compared to in either independent clause, but not both unless the days are different. E.g.

> Thursday will be colder than Wednesday, but we'll probably have less rain than Monday.

That sounds perfectly natural.
And you probably need a certain expression of doubtfulness so I threw the probably in there. Usually, only weathermen (or the people who've watched them) are so certain about the weather as your OP implies.

To the ACTUAL QUESTION:

I don't think its that hard. Don't think of *But with* as one expression; rather, think of it as 2 expressions with fused meanings.

> A but with B = A but A and B

In other words, I think your first sentence and your second sentence have little relation to each other aside from the fact that they mean the same thing.

Comment: Neither sentence will ever appear on its own. So the "missing something to be compared to" will be perfectly clear from context, and there's no need to cram it into the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*with less rain* is correct grammar.
Your first sentence sounds somewhat weird.
It's as if you possess rain.
If you want to say it that way, use *but there will be less rain*.

Comment: Odd as it sounds, it is common to "own" the weather in my region (Midwest, US). "We'll be getting snow tomorrow", "We're going to have a hot one on Tuesday", etc. is perfectly acceptable, though possibly idiomatic or regional.